# What is the Double Stack?

Tags: data-structures

I'm studying now for the final exam and I see the following question at the end of the professor's ppt slides, which are talking about the Stack:

`What is a Double Stack?`

I know that the stack is an ordered collection of homogeneous elements (i.e. a list), in which all insertions and deletions are made at one end of the list called the top of the stackm but what is the double stack? I tried search through google and I had no luck with finding an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be 2 stacks which are stored in a single array and grow in opposite direction.

http://www.ceglug.org/index.php/labs/45-double-stack-implementationwith-structuresand

Though this is the only reference i found.

Answer (score 1):

A DoubleStack is a stack of double values.

You can find more info at

http://www.cis.syr.edu/courses/cis351/docs/edu.colorado.collections.DoubleStack.html.gz

Answer (score 1):

Double stack means two stacks which are implemented using a single array. To prevent memory wastage, the two stacks are grown in opposite direction. The pointer tops1 and tops2 points to top-most element of stack 1 and stack 2 respectively. Initially, tops1 is initialized as -1 and tops2 is initialized the capacity. As the elements are pushed into stack 1, tops1 is incremented. Similarly, as the elements are pushed into stack 2, tops2 is decremented. So, the array is full when tops1=tops2-1. Beyond this, pushing an element into any stack will lead to overflow condition.